# Visual Studio 2017 dependent .dll not found

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a speech recognition children's game using an external API that I want to use on my project. Said API has lib files, dll files, header files and cpp files. As of right now I have successfully added the library files (at least I think I have) to my project directory, added all the necessary header files to external dependencies and I am left to add two .dll files to my project. First, I add my Audio.dll file and it gets added perfectly with no issues. Second, I add my Speech.dll and here is where my problem arises. I don't receieve any errors in my debug error list, however, the output of my project looks like this:

```
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Path\Project.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x3274 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The thread 0x198c has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[17020] Project.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

After this I get a popup System Error: The code execution cannot proceed because Speech.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

No mention of Audio.dll, however, Speech.dll which is in the same folder as Audio.dll isn't being found. I tried reinstalling the .dll, I tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2017, I tried Add->Existing Item->.dll, I tried adding the dll to the project path where the .exe is and I've tried adding it to every folder/subfolder all receiving the same sequence as my output.

My question is, how do I get my visual studio 2017 project to recognize my Speech.dll file?

Comment: It is the most basic possible mishap when using a 3rd party library.  Google "visual studio show loader snaps" for hits.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am knew to c++ and was not entirely aware of this. This helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Please ensure that the `speech.dll` is present in the same folder that your `project.exe` is located.

Windows searches for the `dll`s in the following order:

1. Your application's folder
2. `\windows\system32`
3. etc, according to the Windows defined path

Please ensure that the `dll` is present in any of these folders, otherwise you will get an error that the `dll` missing.

**Note:** If you are debugging then ensure that you have set the Working Directory for debugging correctly to point to the folder containing your `project.exe` and the `dll`.

Comment: It appears that the location being in Path is actually not sufficient for VS to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019 (I'm not aware if this would work on earlier versions),you can copy the DLL as part of the of the build process. Basically you would need to add a **post-build event** to your project. The post-build event would copy the DLL to your build output directory.

For specifying build events see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/specifying-build-events?view=msvc-160

The command you would use for the **post-build event** would be:

```
xcopy /y /d "<relative path or absolute path to dll location>/youlib.dll" "$(outdir)"
```